# App Crash when change orientation in android

Tags: android, android-orientation

App Crash when change orientation in android, I have following error in log cat:

```
 04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.dc.activity/com.project.dc.activity.RunFormActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x0. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
    04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3512)
    04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:130)
    04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
    04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x0. Make sure other views do not use the same id.

   04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1608)
    04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:928)
    04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:900)
    04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1130)
    04-08 11:20:34.389: E/AndroidRuntime(926):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2037)
```

I don't under stand why this is faced. I have many question here, particular some question i faced this problem during change orientation.

I could not track where i faced this error. I know in RunFormActivity.java this occurs, but i have many code in this line so i could not track.

Here, in error same id not used during orientation change, figured out but could not track where it is.

Comment: read this `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x0. Make sure other views do not use the same id.`

Comment: You are using same id for view in your xml file somwhere and after changing orientation because of same id it will be conflicted.

Comment: would you mind to post code for onCreate() of your that activity

Comment: add this in your manifest file in your activity. :: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" i have already added in manifest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your error log line

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x0. Make sure other views do not use the same id.

It shows that you are using the same view for more than two views which not allowed. You can not use the same view id to refer more than one view. Its conflicting while registering your views in `R.java` file.

So make sure to change it in your layout file and clean your project.

Comment: Ok i have trying this. wait for response.

Comment: I am using layout here programmatically. Why some question face such type problem not all.

Comment: Its very difficult to track your code and find error. Please post only the part of code in which you feel the error is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

This type of exception is caused when you giving the same id's. Check out the view's id and make sure others do not use the same id.